# How to Insert breakpoint while gdb is executing

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I want to add some breakpoints while gdb is executing . How to suspend running gdb  and insert breakpoint and continue from there .
I tried ctrl+z , it kills the gdb process.

Comment: Do you pass a certain point in the code when you want to insert the breakpoint? It is possible to create a breakpoint that just insert another.

Comment: I did not get your reply .

Comment: Instead of actually stopping the execution of the program it is possible to activate or set breakpoints at certain points in your code. Either via breakpoints or watchpoints.

Comment: how when gdb is running your code (without stopping the execution ) ?

Comment: I suggest you read the Stopping and Continuing part of the gdb manual I reference in my answer below.

Answer (score 9):

Ctrl-c breaks the execution of your program within gdb, and allows you to insert any breakpoints you like. Stopping is very well explained in the [manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Stopping.html#Stopping). I would suggest you read it, it gives you an huge advantage when debugging.